# Частный обмен/демонстрация кодом/кода

Tags: форматирование

Друг обучается программированию. Мы общаемся по скайпу. Соответственно происходит постоянный обмен кусками кода. Неформатированность чата в скайпе удручает. Что можете посоветовать для обмена такого рода сообщениями? Приватное общение разумеется.

Comment: Приватные пасты на http://pastebin.com/, например.

Или закрытый репозиторий на GitHub или BitBucket.

Comment: благодарю!

Comment: положил исходники на дропбокс, расшарил папку. импортнул исходники в эклипс (на моем и его компе), для того чтоб получить последние исходники достаточно в эклипс нажать "обновить"

Comment: тогда уже лучше git/svn/hg. или дропбок научился решать конфликты?:)

Comment: @jmu стопятидесятая статья на хабре на тему, сегодняшняя: http://habrahabr.ru/post/215513  
И еще добавлю: Вася, Дима и Петя сидят в дропбоксе. Дима внезапно обнаружил глубоко засевшую уязвимость и перебирает свой код буквально с нуля, дропбокс автоматом подхватывает обновления. В это время Петя шлет Васе сообщение "Василий, у меня опять ничего не работает, посмотри чокак", Василий обновляется, и не может загрузить ничего потому что Дмитрий сломал ВСЕ. Работа над проектом в этот момент встает до того момента, пока Дмитрий не починит все и не получит по шапке.

Comment: 1) почему вы решили что я не знаю что такое система контроля версий ?  
2) моя задача стояла: максимально быстро реализовать обмен исходниками между 2мя компами (мне понадибилось в сию минуту, поэтому времени на рег в бесплатных сайтах/разворачивание своего хранилища времени небыло)  
3) задача ученика выполнять задания, моя - делать `code review`, правкой кода я не занимаюсь, а если и делаю то только когда просматриваю готовое. соответсвенно в 2х сторонней синхронизации нет нужды
4) тестовые задания это несколько файлов  

или вы считаете что все же лучше "из пушки по воробьям" ?

Comment: @jmu, потому что в комментарии не было ни единого намека на знание cvs.

> или вы считаете что все же лучше "из пушки по воробьям" ?

Вообще нет, но лично мое мнение состоит в том, что cvs, тестирование и прочее надо прививать на самых ранних этапах.

Comment: @Fike перфекционизм ради перфекционизма, ничего не стоит. смысл учить человека пользоваться репозиториями который еще толком программирование не выучил? репозитории нужны когда идет совместная робота над кодом или нужно иметь гарантии соханности данных

p.s. в вопросе тоже не было упоминания о том что автор умеет пользоватся cvs, но почему-то никто на это не обратил внимание

Comment: @jmu, вы сейчас объясняете мне, как именно я считаю?

Answer (score 3):

воспользуйтесь специальным сервисом, гуглиться по словам "collaborate edit". Первое рабочее, что нашел - http://collabedit.com/

Суть. Создаете новый документ, вводите свой никнейм. Полученную ссылку отправляете другу. Он также вводит свое имя. В результате оба могут одновременно редактировать и видеть текущий код. С подсветкой. А скайп - для голоса.

Answer (score 2):

http://pastebin.com -> зарегистрироваться и выбрать видимость "private"
можно поставить git и обмениваться напрямую без каких-либо посредников, хотя это будут уже не просто куски кода, а именно модификация сурсов.